# How Doze (marshmallow feature) work during playback?

Tags: battery, battery-life, 6.0-marshmallow, standby

We know that Doze mode starts the 'ultra power saving' when the device isn't moving.

But what happen if we leave the device on a table playing music with the screen off?

**EDIT:** I experienced the volume decreased after sometime when playing with Google Music app. Is this a feature of the app or some intrusion of the Doze ?

Comment: Related:   [Doze mode and foreground service](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33077301)

Comment: Related: [how-many-idle-time-is-needed-to-doze-start-its-job](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130055/how-many-idle-time-is-needed-to-doze-start-its-job)