# How much (Idle) time is needed for "Doze" to get activated ? (Android 6- Marshmallow)

Tags: battery-life, 6.0-marshmallow, standby, smart-lock

Consider a device that was left on a table, unplugged, and no movement. After sometime, the screen turns off, and the screen lock *may (or may not) be* auto activated, according to lock and smart lock settings.

- Firstly, let's assume its locked, how much time is required for *Doze*, working to save power?
- On the other hand, if the smart lock is acting (like by geographic location), keeping device unlocked for several hours (is six the limit, right?), how will this affect "Doze" functionality?

Answer (score 4):

- First part of your question "*Firstly, let's assume its locked, how much time is required for Doze, working to save power?*"

Idle time is **not** specified by Google and I *guess* this is implemented differently by OEMs

Quoting from Google documentation  [Optimising for Doze and stand by](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)  (emphasis added)

> If a user leaves a device unplugged and stationary for a **period of time**, with the screen off, the device enters Doze mode. In Doze mode, the system attempts to conserve battery by restricting apps' access to network and CPU-intensive services. It also prevents apps from accessing the network and defers their jobs, syncs, and standard alarms.
>
> Periodically, the system exits Doze for a brief time to let apps complete their deferred activities. During this maintenance window, the system runs all pending syncs, jobs, and alarms, and lets apps access the network.

**Edit** : This may answer from a user perspective as this is what developers are apparently planning **9 minute interval**

**Source** https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/94jCkmG4jff

> Dianne Hackborn**17 Nov 2015**
> +Petr Nalevka Sorry scheduling alarms so frequently is currently not supported in doze....For what it's worth, the minimum time between while idle alarms will be changing to **9 minutes at some point relatively soon (even on devices running the current Marshmallow builds)**.

- Second part of your question "*.... if the smart lock is acting (like by geographic location), keeping device unlocked for several hours (is six the limit, right?), how will this affect "Doze" functionality?* (and a related question of yours [How Doze (marshmallow feature) work during playback?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130053/how-doze-marshmallow-feature-work-during-playback))

It is difficult to answer this correctly as

1. As can be seen from the answer to first part of question, developers seem to be improving / modifying the behaviour of "Doze" functionality and only once it is matured and implemented, one can reach a conclusion.
2. As can be seen in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018306/doze-mode-and-foreground-service, thanks to [Firelord for highlighting this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130053/how-doze-marshmallow-feature-work-during-playback#comment162198_130053)
   , documentation by Google is lacking in details and developers/ OEM may implement varying behaviors, so nothing can be said at this point of time with certainty.